# Failed to apply plugin [id 'android-library']

Tags: android, android-studio

when I want to clear or build my app in the android studio I get this error

```
ailed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
> Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'.
  > com/android/utils/ILogger
```

> my android studio is 3.0.1
>   gradle plugin 3.0.1

Comment: You must supply more information like, when did this start, did this build succeed before, code?

Comment: your information is not sufficient to figure out the problem. You should add some more details

Comment: it starts just today I open my old project and update my android studio and plugin and I don't know it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem :)
I just delete gradle folder in C:\Users\userName.gradle
then rebuild my project and download all gradle plugins